# C# winforms function return value

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, function

I have some problems with the return value of a function of mine.  What I'm tryng to do is to get an element value from `XML_File` and return the value so I can use it in `Form_Load`.

I tried to process the `XML_Array_Load` function and I got the error below.  (The `Form_Load` hasn't been tested because of the error in the other function.)

XML_Array_Load Function Error:

> Error  1   Since 'Program.Form1.XML_Array_Load(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

C# code:

```
    static void XML_Array_Load(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array, Dictionary<string, string> Elements_Array)
    {
        // XML File
        String xmlfile = Data_Array["XML_File"];

        // XML Page Check
        if (File.Exists(xmlfile))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            // If Page Exist Load XML File
            doc.Load(xmlfile);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Element in Elements_Array)
            {
                // Get Element From Dictionary Array
                String Element_Name = Element.Key;
                String Element_Type = Element.Value;

                // Get Element_Name from XMLFile
                String Value = String.Format("XMLFILE/{0}", Element_Name);

                // Get Element_Name Value From XMLFile
                XmlNode Element_Value = doc.SelectSingleNode(Value);

                // Check If Element_Value Is Null Or Not
                if (Element_Value != null)
                {
                    return Element_Value;
                }

            }
        }
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start Data Array
        Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // XML_File path is come here
        Data_Array.Add("XML_File", "../Debug/XMLFiles/Settings.xml");

        // This is the element what i need to get the value from XML_File
        Elements_Array.Add("Active", "");

        // Send Arrays To Function and get function result
        String Return_Value = XML_Array_Insert(Data_Array, Elements_Array);

        // Here will setup textBox4.Text with the value
        textBox4.Text = Return_Value.InnerText;
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to return, a `XmlNode` or a `string`?

Comment: nice try. yesterday, you've earned massive downvotes for asking unconstructive/duplicate questions under your old name 'matei zoc'. today, you take a new name und start the same question type? fabulous.

Answer (score 2):

You declared your method as `static void XML_Array_Load()`. `void` means it doesn't return any value. And then you tried to return a value.

You can't do that. If you want the method to return a value, declare it as such.

```
static XmlNode XML_Array_Load(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, the method has a return type of void, which means it returns nothing.  If you want it to return something then you'll need to change `void` to whatever you want it to return.

You have several other issues with your code.  Where you call the method seems to expect it to return a string, but within the method itself it's returning an `XmlNode`.  You'll need to pick one of the two to return, and alter one of those two locations to be consistent with that choice.

You also have your `return` statement inside of a `foreach` loop.  You can only `return` one value, so what you'll end up doing is returning the first non-null value the collection.  Is that actually what you want?  This is a rather unusual thing to see.

Answer (score 0):

1 Replace void with return type

```
static XmlNode  XML_Array_Load(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array, Dictionary<string, string> Elements_Array)
```

2 And add return in the end of your function in order to ensure that all path return value

```
...
return null;
}
```

Result :

```
static XmlNode   XML_Array_Load(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array, Dictionary<string, string> Elements_Array)
    {
        // XML File
        String xmlfile = Data_Array["XML_File"];

        // XML Page Check
        if (File.Exists(xmlfile))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            // If Page Exist Load XML File
            doc.Load(xmlfile);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Element in Elements_Array)
            {
                // Get Element From Dictionary Array
                String Element_Name = Element.Key;
                String Element_Type = Element.Value;

                // Get Element_Name from XMLFile
                String Value = String.Format("XMLFILE/{0}", Element_Name);

                // Get Element_Name Value From XMLFile
                XmlNode Element_Value = doc.SelectSingleNode(Value);

                // Check If Element_Value Is Null Or Not
                if (Element_Value != null)
                {
                    return Element_Value;
                }

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```